# looking for ordered list of results brings up a "no results found" with Beautiful soup

Tags: beautifulsoup

the code is simple, it searches through a bing search of choice and prints out the results,
the problem is that the results variable returns that it didnt find anything, even though I searched in the console and found that exact id
I cant quite understand why this happens and any help would be appreciated, thanks

Updated code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
params = {"q": "test"}
r = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/search", params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find("ol", {"id": "b_results"})
print(results)
```

the expected result would be the search and collection of the first instance of an ordered list with and id of b_results of the webpage, "print(results)" is written in just so we can see the output, it has no use in the original code.

result from `print(soup.prettify())`:

```
 <ol id="b_results">
      <li class="b_no">
       <h1>
        No results for
        <strong>
         test
        </strong>
       </h1>
       <ul>
        <li>
         <span>
          Check spelling or try a different keyword
         </span>
        </li>
       </ul>
       <br/>
```

Comment: does HTML appear in `print(soup.prettify())`?

Comment: @Greg
I ran the print and the html shows up, here are the first lines of the response:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="es" xml:lang="es" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:web="http://schemas.live.com/Web/"> `

Comment: That the html processed by Beautiful soup. Does it contain `<li class='b_algo'>`? If not then you won't be able to scrape it. Most likely html is generated by JavaScript .

Comment: @Greg it does, theres a bunch of children of the "ol" that are li class = "b_algo", at least they appear in the browser console of that page

Comment: I've just ran your code. For search I typed in `test`. It returned 1 results. It printed out `Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer`, `https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/?tabid=mha`. - Can you update your question with a repeatable minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? Along with the expected output?

Comment: @Greg Updated the code as requested, I also made the search word be test from the start, I should add that your print result is different from mine which says that there has been no result and I should try another keyword

Comment: @Greg I now have found out that this stems from the soup, when I ran `print(soup.prettify())` the result shown in the b_results section is not what is wanted and i added it to the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bing is treating the `request` from Python code differently to a web request in the browser. One way to get around this is to pass in the `user-agent` in the headers.

For current version of Chrome:  `{"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"}`

**For example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
params = {"q": "test"}
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/search", params=params, headers =headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find("ol", {"id": "b_results"})
print(results)
```